# Why does my password appear in clear text with my smartphone mail IMAP application?

Tags: email, smtp, smartphone, imap

I am using the default Galaxy 5 mail application to fetch my mail with IMAP.

Packet capture shows my user and password in clear text (see below).

**Why does my username and password appear in clear text and how to change my configuration to avoid this?**

---

Following the TCP stream with `wireshark`, I get (see  and )

```
* OK IMAP# PROXY server ready
#### CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP#rev# UIDPLUS IDLE LOGIN-REFERRALS NAMESPACE QUOTA CHILDREN AUTH=CRAM-MD# AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR
#### OK capabilities listed
#### LOGIN <USERNAME> "<PASSWORD>"
#### OK login successful
#### NAMESPACE
* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
#### OK NAMESPACE completed
#### NOOP
#### OK NOOP complete
#### CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP#rev# UIDPLUS IDLE LOGIN-REFERRALS NAMESPACE QUOTA CHILDREN SORT THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES X-CP-MOVE MOVE X-CP-MODIFY-HEADER AUTH=DIGEST-MD# SASL-IR
#### OK capabilities listed
#### LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Courrier ind&AOk-sirable"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Drafts
* LIST (\NoInferiors) NIL INBOX
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Junk
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Archive"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Outbox"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Schedules"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Trashbin"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Spam
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Trash
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Unwanted
#### OK LIST completed
#### NOOP
#### OK NOOP complete
#### SELECT "INBOX"
* #### EXISTS
* # RECENT
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $MDNSent FORWARDED $Forwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $MDNSent FORWARDED $Forwarded)] flags can be changed
* OK [UIDVALIDITY ##########] mailbox UID validity
* OK [UNSEEN ####] first unseen message number
* OK [UIDNEXT #####] predicted next UID
#### OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT complete
#### UID SEARCH all since ##-Nov-####
* SEARCH ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### #####
#### OK SEARCH complete
#### UID FETCH #####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,##### (UID FLAGS)
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen $Forwarded))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen $Forwarded))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
#### OK FETCH complete
* OK IMAP# PROXY server ready
#### CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP#rev# UIDPLUS IDLE LOGIN-REFERRALS NAMESPACE QUOTA CHILDREN AUTH=CRAM-MD# AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR
#### OK capabilities listed
#### LOGIN ############# "#########"
#### OK login successful
#### NAMESPACE
* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
#### OK NAMESPACE completed
#### NOOP
#### OK NOOP complete
#### CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP#rev# UIDPLUS IDLE LOGIN-REFERRALS NAMESPACE QUOTA CHILDREN SORT THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES X-CP-MOVE MOVE X-CP-MODIFY-HEADER AUTH=DIGEST-MD# SASL-IR
#### OK capabilities listed
#### LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Courrier ind&AOk-sirable"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Drafts
* LIST (\NoInferiors) NIL INBOX
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Junk
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Archive"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Outbox"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Schedules"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "SMS BOX archiv/Trashbin"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Spam
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Trash
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Unwanted
#### OK LIST completed
#### NOOP
#### OK NOOP complete
#### SELECT "INBOX"
* #### EXISTS
* # RECENT
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $MDNSent FORWARDED $Forwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $MDNSent FORWARDED $Forwarded)] flags can be changed
* OK [UIDVALIDITY ##########] mailbox UID validity
* OK [UNSEEN ####] first unseen message number
* OK [UIDNEXT #####] predicted next UID
#### OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT complete
#### UID SEARCH all since ##-Nov-####
* SEARCH ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### ##### #####
#### OK SEARCH complete
#### UID FETCH #####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,#####,##### (UID FLAGS)
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen $Forwarded))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS ())
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen $Forwarded))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
* #### FETCH (UID ##### FLAGS (\Seen))
#### OK FETCH complete
```

Comment: Ekhm... Because that's how IMAP protocol works. How to avoid? Get an application which uses IMAP over SSL or reconfigure your current one. What is this question about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears in cleartext because you don't use transport layer security (tls) when connecting to your mail host.

In order to change it, reconfigure your mail account on the galaxy  (both the incoming and outgoing mail server) and choose ssl or tls for the security type field. You find this under the mail account's server options/server configuration. Depending on your mail host, it might also be necessary to change the suggested port number.

Not all mail providers support tls (and not all of them on the same ports, though usually the default ports the mail app suggests should work). If you're stuck with one that doesn't provide it, you have no choice but to transmit the cleartext password.